# How to lay out a Container, I dont know W&H

Tags: flutter

How to lay out a Container, I don't know W&H

```
only know margin  left&right 15.0     top:20.0    bottom:30.0

Scaffold->Container->Column->**Container**
```

Like this :

[image]

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
  body: Column(                                   
    children: [                                   
      Expanded(                                   
        child: Container(                         
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(               
            left: 15.0,                           
            right: 15.0,                          
            top: 20.0,                            
            bottom: 30.0,                         
          ),                                      
          child: Center(                          
            child: Text('child'),                 
          ),                                      
        ),                                        
      ),                                          
    ],                                            
  ),
```